# Как в качестве параметра функции передать оператор сложения( + )

Tags: javascript

Нужно подобие такого кода:

```
let func = (prop) => {
   if(2 prop 2 == 4) {
      console.log('Ура! Работает!');
   }
}

func('+');
```

Только рабочее. Не могу понять, как в качестве параметра передать +
т.е. по сути, если правильно задать условие это будет выглядеть как

```
if(2 + 2 == 4) {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать то, чего просто нет в синтаксисе языка) Но можно оформить это как-то по другому:

```js
let calc = getCalcTool(); // При вызове, функция создает объект `local_math`
  // И возвращает функцию, которая присваивается в `calc`. 
  // При вызове, calc будет помнить созданный объект и доставать оттуда нужные функции

if (calc(3, "+", 2) === 5) console.log("√");
if (calc(3, "-", 2) === 1) console.log("√");
if (calc(3, "*", 2) === 6) console.log("√");
if (calc(3, "/", 2) === 1.5) console.log("√");


function getCalcTool() {
  let local_math = {
    "+": (a, b) => a + b,
    "-": (a, b) => a - b,
    "/": (a, b) => a / b,
    "*": (a, b) => a * b,
  };

  return function(a, operator, b) {
    return local_math[operator](a, b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну так немного нельзя...
Максимум - функция `eval()`. Она js-вычисляет строковое значение:

```
eval('2+3');    // 5

const func = (prop) => {
    if (eval(`2 ${prop} 2`) == 4) console.log('Вот теперь получилось');
}

func('+');    // Вот теперь получилось
```

Правда, eval использовать очень не рекомендуют. Это не безопасно

Answer (score -2):

```js
let func = (prop) => {
   if(prop(2, 2) == 4) {
      console.log('Ура! Работает!');
   }
}
func((a, b) => a + b)
```